# 3D issue with CSS3 using PhantomJS

Tags: css, 3d, phantomjs

**Info**

I am currently working on a native/server project where one important step is to render a HTML/CSS animated 3D cube into a video. I am using *[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)* and *FFmpeg* for the video part.

The 3D cube is in a `div`, which is inside a container, in the HTML code. On the CSS side, the cube gets animated in CSS3 using media queries as seen below.

**Question**

This 3D cube works fine when looking at it using a web browser, but when it gets rendered into a PNG the whole cube looks flat as a paper. Tearing down the code, I noticed *PhantomJS* is ignoring the `preserve-3d`. If you commentate the `preserve-3d` away, you will get the same result as the PNG´s using *PhantomJS*.

Also, using `translateZ`, `rotateY` and `rotateX` seems not to be working as intended. Mainly because of the `preserve-3d` problem.

Any ideas on how I should proceed with this problem?

P.S. I have also tried using `-moz-transform`, `-o-transform`, `-ms-transform` and `transform` instead of `-webkit-transform`, did not work.

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="cube" class="animate">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinning {
  from  {-webkit-transform: translateX(200px) rotateZ(100deg) rotateY(0deg);   }
  to    {-webkit-transform: translateX(100px) rotateZ(200deg) rotateY(220deg);   }
}

#container {
  -webkit-perspective           : 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin    : 50% 50%;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation : spinning 5s 1 linear;
  -webkit-transform : translateX(100px) rotateZ(200deg) rotateY(220deg);
}

#cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

  -webkit-transition        : -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style   : preserve-3d;
}

#cube>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-position:center center;
}

/* =======================================
   ======= Placement of each side ======== 
   ======================================= */


#cube div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform : translateZ(100px);
  background-color  : #09F;
}

#cube div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  background-color  : #0F9;
}

#cube div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
  background-color  : #99C;
}

#cube div:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  background-color  : #F6C;
}

#cube div:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
  background-color  : #939;
}

#cube div:nth-child(6)  {
  -webkit-transform : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  background-color  : #F63;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am finding unusual behaviour with `transform: matrix3d` in phantom

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PhantomJS does **not** support CSS3 3D transform, yet.

Here is an old article from 2012 for more information.

[Google forum article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/h7-4-CWsy1g/KX1tlf5gT5IJ)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @gustavohenke The first sentence does provide an answer.